How to Resolve Crystal Report Temp File Error in Visual Studio 2019?
I am trying to build connection using Crystal report in Visual Studio 2019. but while running crystal report facing below issue.

Error in File temp_{}.rpt: Database connector Error.

I tried to set Target Platform to x86 and Active(AnyCPU) but both not worked.
